# Sole Tenancy option mandatory for instance from image with OS on Cloud Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, vdi

When I create an Image from a vdi-file in Cloud Engine I have the option to choose if there is an operating system on the virtual disk or not (Data only). If I choose Windows 10 (x64) as the OS I need to configure a *Sole Tenancy* if I want to create an instance from the image.
Why is this mandatory if a OS is present on the virtual disk?
Thank You!

Comment: Just wondering if you are following/referring this document [1]  for creating VM instances from image .According to this, as a optional part, If you chose an OS image that supports Shielded VM features, you can modify the settings from ‘Management, security, disks, networking, sole tenancy’ option.you can take a look at details on Sole-tenant nodes [2].
[1]https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#startinginstancewithimage
[2]https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/sole-tenant-nodes

Comment: Hi @Shanewaz thanks for the reply. Yes, I was following/referring to these documents. I was just wondering why google cloud made the sole tenancy mandatory for starting an instance from an image with predefined OS. Maybe my whole approach was wrong. I solved it by following these steps: [link](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/compute-image-tools/image-import.html)

Comment: hi, @Gunnar I'm trying exactly the same and GCP forces me to use sole tenancy which I don't want. Did you manage to spin up the Windows instance in GCP without using sole tenancy? The link you've provided, does not work anymore. Thanks

Comment: any update? Gunnar's link does not work anymore